# I am trying to find the scrabble value of a word using C program

Tags: c, char, parentheses, operator-precedence, getchar

I am always getting the value of each letter I enter as 1 whereas I should get the values as described in the code. Please help find the error in my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char c;

char num (char c);

int main () {
    int sum;

    printf("Enter a word:");

    c=0;

        while (c=getchar() != '\n') {
            c=toupper(c);
            sum+=c;
        }

    printf("Scrabble value : %d",sum);

    return(0);
}

char num (char c) {

    if (c=='A'||c=='E'||c=='I'||c=='L'||c=='N'||c=='O'||c=='R'||c=='S'||c=='T'||c=='U') c=1;
    if (c=='D'||c=='G') c=2;
    if (c=='B'||c=='C'||c=='M'||c=='P') c=3;
    if (c=='F'||c=='H'||c=='V'||c=='W'||c=='Y') c=4;
    if (c=='K') c=5;
    if (c=='J'||c=='X') c=8;
    if (c=='Q'||c=='Z') c=10;

    return(c);
}
```

Comment: And where do you use `num(char c)` in your code ;-) ?

Comment: The expression `c=getchar() != '\n'` is, due to [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), equal to `c=(getchar() != '\n')`. This means the value of `c` will be either `0` or `1`, and nothing else. Also note that [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an `int`, which is important to check for `EOF`. Lastly, you need to check for `EOF` or errors in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, this will work for you (call num; fixed getchar call in while; initialized sum to 0; no error handling):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char c;

char num (char c);

int main () {
    int sum = 0;

    printf("Enter a word:");

    c=0;

        while ((c=getchar()) != '\n') {
            c=toupper(c);
            sum+=num(c);
        }

    printf("Scrabble value : %d",sum);

    return(0);
}

char num (char c) {

    if (c=='A'||c=='E'||c=='I'||c=='L'||c=='N'||c=='O'||c=='R'||c=='S'||c=='T'||c=='U') c=1;
    if (c=='D'||c=='G') c=2;
    if (c=='B'||c=='C'||c=='M'||c=='P') c=3;
    if (c=='F'||c=='H'||c=='V'||c=='W'||c=='Y') c=4;
    if (c=='K') c=5;
    if (c=='J'||c=='X') c=8;
    if (c=='Q'||c=='Z') c=10;

    return(c);
}
```

Comment: Catching things like "_" and " " (though of course forbidden in scrabble) would improve this.

Comment: @Yunnosch Sure, but I explicitly wrote there is no error handling ;-)

Comment: Thank You so much. I understood my mistake in the precedence order.

Comment: @NikhilBoddupalli You are welcome! But also thank the other guys, I just summarized it.

Comment: You should change char c to int.

Answer (score 1):

To get this clean, init sum:

```
int sum = 0;
```

The logic of your function for determining the value looks OK (maybe apart from the return value),
but you constantly change the parameter `c`. This does not actually break anything, but looks somewhat confusing. I recommend to change all `c= something` to `return something;`.

To have a default handling, change `return(c);` to `return 0;`.

Also you never call your function.

Change

```
sum+=c;
```

to

```
sum+=num(c);
```

Picking up from (absolutely necessary) comment by Some programmer dude (credits),
The expression `c=getchar() != '\n'` is, due to operator precedence, equal to `c=(getchar() != '\n')`. This means the value of `c` will be either `0` or `1`, and nothing else. Also note that `getchar` returns an int, which is important to check for `EOF`. Lastly, you need to check for `EOF` or errors in general.

Comment: Without the `getchar()` parenthesis fix from Some programmer dude this will also not be sufficient to work correctly.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName That is why I included the comment as soon as I realised. Only using that does not help either however.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already answered the question, but just for reference, this is how you write a better look-up function:

```
int get_val (char c)
{
  const int VALUES ['Z' - 'A' + 1] =
  {
    ['A' - 'A'] = 1,
    ['B' - 'A'] = 3,
    ['C' - 'A'] = 3,
    ...
  };

  return VALUES[c - 'A'];
}
```

Comment: Reply to the mandatory incoming BS comment about EBCDIC: "Ye ye heard it all before, add this anywhere in the code:  `_Static_assert('Z'-'A' == 25, "Crap not supported");`".